# How do you remove a colonized habitat?

Tags: stellaris

In my capital system, there are 8 planetary bodies, of which I created 7 habitats around and then colonized. Now that the Worm loves us and always has, I now have 6 colonized worlds instead of just the 1 I had started with. However, I can't build starports on the 5 worlds that contain orbital habitats. I don't see any options for destroying them. How can I remove them so I can build starports around these new colonized planets?

Comment: Star ports can only be built on colonized planets. I'm not exactly following your question but it seems like you're trying to build star ports on non-colonized planets which isn't a thing.

Comment: @n_palum: No. My system started with 1 colonized system, but after following the Worm event, I now have **6** colonized worlds. Unfortunately, I had already created habitats around the other 5 worlds that are now colonized.

Comment: Ahh I see. Yeah I'm not sure there is a way to remove them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Habitats cannot be destroyed by you.

However, there is one option, though this is only realistic in a multiplayer game.

There is the war demand "disassemble Habitat", available to xenophobes or any empire with access to purging populations and cleansing planets. If it is enforced at the end of the war, the chosen habitat will be destroyed.

Relying on the AI to pick this war demand is not a good idea, but if it is multiplayer, you could ask another player to declare war on you, demand the disassembly of your habitats, you surrender and all your habitats are gone.

Comment: So, I tried doing this in single player by creating a vassal out of the system so I can declare war on it. However, I don't see any war goals having to do with disassembling habitats. I can cede/liberate them, just like the planets in the system, and that's about it.

Comment: Disassemble Habitat has the same requirements as cleansing a planet. So, you need xenophobic ethics to do it. I added that to the answer.

Comment: @Dulkan Just curious: Are xenophobic war demands available when the enemy is the same species as you?

Comment: Ok, so the multi-step process for single player is: 1) Changing governing ethics to add xenophobic if not already, 2) Move capital to a different system, 3) Turn the entire system into a vassal faction, 4) Depending on situation, declare war on vassal or release vassal, wait 10 years, and then declare war on the faction, 5) Demand habitats are disassembled, 6) Take the system back by force, 7) Deal with other ramifications. That's a lot of work that I probably won't get to implement in this particular game unless an end-game crisis spawns that really draws things out.