# What conditions must exist to have the disassemble habitat war demand to be available?

Tags: stellaris

So, I tried a little experiment to [fix a small problem I inadvertently created](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/325362/how-do-you-remove-a-colonized-habitat) which boiled down to declaring war on faction that I established which owned only a single system that I gifted to them. In that system are 6 colonized worlds and 5 colonized habitats around those worlds (plus 2 other colonized habitats around inhospitable worlds), all populated with members of my species. I was expecting the "disassemble habitat" war demand to be available, but it was no where to be found. I had the typical humiliate/cede/liberate/vassalize options for both the planets and habitats, but that's it.

Is there specific criteria that needs to be met in order to be able to select a war demand to disassemble habitats as opposed to liberating or taking them over?

Comment: Related: [How do you remove a colonized habitat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/325362/how-do-you-remove-a-colonized-habitat?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Disassemble Habitat wargoal is the habitat equivalent of Cleanse Planet. It has the same requirements- you must have purges enabled.